# Is there any way to combine the facet_wrap_paginate function with the grid.arrange function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

What I would like is to use the facet_wrap_paginate function to generate each page with 3 plots on each page, hence the use of the grid.arrange function. The number of pages will be based on the count of the variables that I have facet wrapped.

Right now I can only display one ggplot at a time on each page using a for function.

```
z < - ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = 
        hwy)) + geom_point() +
        facet_wrap_paginate(~cyl, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, page = i)
n <- n_pages(z)
pdf('Cars.pdf', paper= 'A4', w= 210/25.4, 297/25.4)
for(i in 1:n) {print(ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = 
        hwy)) + geom_point() +
        facet_wrap_paginate(~cyl, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, page = i))
        } 
dev.off()
```

Comment: Is there something about setting `nrow = 3` or `ncol = 3` that you like to avoid?

Comment: Yeah I would just like 1 facet for each plot on one page.

Comment: Yeah I got that from your question, I meant more specifically what would be the benefit of seperating the plots by facets and then recombining them again. It seems a bit counterintuitive to me, unless you want to preserve something specific (limits, labels, breaks etc).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. The only reason I would like to use this method is because I could compare multiple plots of different variables on one page, if that makes sense? At the moment, there are too many plots on one page so it is difficult to make sense of the visualisation using the dataset I am using, especially with overlapping points from geom_point. By keeping to one facet a page, it is much easier to interpret.